# Two way searching a list of tuples

Tags: haskell

```
tuplesList = [('a','m'), ('b', 'n'), ('c', 'o'), etc]
```

How do I search this list for a value by first looking at first elements and returning the second if found, but if not found then look at the second elements and return the first element if found. e.g. searching for 'a' would return 'm' and searching for 'n' returns 'b'?

I tried this:

```
lookup :: Char -> [(Char,Char)] -> Char

lookup x zs = (head [b | (a,b) <- zs, (a==x)])

lookup x zs = (head [a | (a,b) <- zs, (b==x)])
```

but I don't know how to say if the the 2nd line doesn't find a match then do the 3rd line.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haskell already has [its own `lookup` function](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Prelude.html#g:18) which you should probably make use of:

```
lookup' :: Char -> [(Char,Char)] -> Char
lookup' x zs = case (search1, search2) of
                    (Just y,  _)       -> y
                    (Nothing, Just y)  -> y
                    (Nothing, Nothing) -> error "What am I supposed to do here I DON'T KNOW"
 where search1 = lookup x zs
       search2 = lookup x [(b,a) | (a,b) <- zs]
```

Comment: `Alternative` from `Control.Applicative` would be handy here: `lookup' x zs = lookup x zs <|> lookup x (fmap swap zs)`

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to expand your partial solution is to just concatenate the two lists of candidates together, as in:

```
lookup x zs = head ([ b | (a,b) <- zs, a == x ] ++ [ a | (a,b) <- zs, b == x ])
```

Do you see why this works?

---

It's not maximally efficient, because if there's no match on the first component of the tuples it will go through `zs` twice - if `zs` is very large this holds on to zs longer than necessary.

In order to improve that I would do something like this (but only if it's very important!):

```
lookup x zs = goNoSecondBestYet zs where
    goNoSecondBestYet [] = error "Nothing found"
    goNoSecondBestYet ((a,b):abs) 
        | a == x = b -- we're done!
        | b == x = goSecondBestFound b abs -- keep track of the newly found second best candidate
        | otherwise = goNoSecondBestYet abs -- just go on
    goSecondBestFound y [] = y
    goSecondBestFound y ((a,b):abs)
        | a == x = b -- we're done, never mind the second best
        | otherwise = goSecondBestFound y abs -- keep going, we already have a second best
```

This is pretty complex already (try to generalise this to use 4-tuples to see what I mean!) and I would normally use `Maybe` for this; but it *does* go through the list only once.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider that a lookup may fail. The natural thing to do here is to return a list of results:

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> (a,a) -> [a]
lookup item xs = [ if a==c then b else a | (a,b) <- xs, a == c || b == c ]
```

Comment: `lookup` usually returns a Maybe.

Comment: Yes, @ReinHenrichs, I know, but a list is **at least** as good as a Maybe, and since we have a list anyway it is simply not wise to construct another type here. As soon as you do that by prefixing the whole thing with listToMaybe or some such and as soon as you fixed all occurences where this function was used, the idea comes up to check for the second match. Or the last match.

Comment: A list is not at least as good as a Maybe: a list cannot represent exactly zero or one results. Also, there is value in interface consistency.